# Django - Saving thumbnail with different filename

Tags: django

I want to create thumbnails of uploaded image files and save them with "_th" at the end of the filename. Currently, I am using the following code:

```
def _create_thumbnail(img_path):
    image = Image.open(img_path)

    if image.mode not in ("L", "RGB"):
        image = image.convert("RGB")

    image.thumbnail(MEDIA_THUMBNAIL_SIZES, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    return image.save(img_path, 'JPEG', quality=MEDIA_THUMBNAIL_QUALITY)
```

It overwrites the original file. Is there a way to easily change the name of the file to include _th before the file extension and save it in the same place?

Also, I am saving the thumbnail after the post save signal using the following method:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Media, dispatch_uid="media_create_thumb")
def create_media_thumbnail(sender, **kwargs):
    thumb = generate_thumbnail(kwargs['instance'].file)
```

I was wondering if this is an ok (pythonic?) way of using signals? Since I am not using the django admin panel, using the admins post save isn't an option.

This method to create thumbnails will be open to users, so if there is anything about the above code which might cause problems, I'd appreciate the heads up!

Comment: Django has nothing to do with thumbnail generation, it seems you're using another library.
Could you tell us where your Image class comes from ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try the following:

```
import os

(head, tail) = os.path.split(img_path)
(name,ext)=tail.split('.')
tail=name+'_th.'+ext
img_path=os.path.join(head,tail)
```

**edit:**
as i found out recently, you can even shortcut that:

```
(name,ext)=os.path.splitext(img_path)
img_path = name + '_th.' + ext
```

Comment: Is it ok to use the os module on a live server? I always thought it was just a quick hack fo getting things working locally.

Comment: os is just a python module creating operation system interfaces. How you use them is up to you. you can create severe damage with it (writing and deleting important files ie.), so handle with care, but yes, you can use it for production. You can find the python docs here: http://docs.python.org/library/os.html